# kubectl called in jenkins fails but works fine in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, jenkins

I am trying to call simple kubectl commands from Jenkins for my Azure

Jenkins is installed jumpbox which is connected to AKS and ACR. kubectl commands run perfectly fine in the terminal however fail when called from Jenkins.

Below is the Jenkins script

```
        stage('Deploy Image') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying Image to AKS ....'
                withKubeConfig(caCertificate: '', clusterName: '', contextName: '', credentialsId: '', namespace: 'icx-preprod', restrictKubeConfigAccess: false, serverUrl: '') 
                // sh 'kubectl delete statetfulset dpms -n icx-preprod'
                sh 'kubectl apply -f /home/icx-user/nonwebpa-yamls/rt/rt.yaml -n preprod'
            }
        }
```

and errors are

```
+ kubectl apply -f /home/icx-user/nonwebpa-yamls/rt/rt.yaml -n preprod
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

and

```
+ kubectl get pods -n preprod
E1010 07:30:08.881057   47786 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
E1010 07:30:08.897305   47786 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
E1010 07:30:08.910836   47786 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
E1010 07:30:08.931700   47786 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
E1010 07:30:08.950612   47786 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
[Pipeline] }
[kubernetes-cli] kubectl configuration cleaned up
```

https://apc01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fconsole%2Fdevelopers%2F4840033536279633147%2Fapp%2F4976273181126489285%2Fvitals%2Fmetrics%2Fdetails%3Fmetric%3DUSER_PERCEIVED_ANRS&data=05%7C01%7Cashwin.r%40tataelxsi.co.in%7C1f0dd762e80a47f9e0d408dbf62dce21%7Cad6a39dd96b6436882daf2ec4d92e26a%7C0%7C0%7C638374448812960079%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=ucrHoMNUK%2FCFfkyhKOc%2FOcy3yLs2lUC%2BmjVGpOjxZ9o%3D&reserved=0

Comment: Compare the output of `kubectl config view` from command line and from jenkins.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Thanks only apiVersion and Kind are coming up equal as v1 and Config resp. remaining values such clusters, config all are coming as null...kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so basically we need to do "az login" within Jenkins before we call "kubectl"

sample code

```
                    // Login to Azure CLI using Service Principal
                    sh 'az login --service-principal -u <client_id> -p <client_secret> -t <tenant_id>'
                    sh 'az account set --subscription <subscription_name>'
                    // Connect with kube cluster
                    sh 'az aks get-credentials --overwrite-existing --resource-group <resource_group_name> --name <cluster_name>'
                    sh 'kubectl get pods -n <namespace>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically K8s api-server is not reachable from jenkins is because you've not configure the right k8s api in jenkins or the plugin that you're using is deprecated. You can also use kube-config in jenkins server to interact to kubernetes.

Comment: How to fix this please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).